# Get Element to Fade in and Out on Hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an element containing a paragraph that I'd like to briefly fade in and out when the parent element is hovered over. I'd also like the fade to reset each time the user's pointer leaves the parent so that the effect is duplicated when the pointer re-enters the parent element. I also need this to work in IE7, so no CSS3 for me. Thanks in advance for recommended solutions . . .

```
<div id="element">
<p class="child">I need to fade in and out</p>
</div>

#element {
color: #fff;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #000;
}
.child {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: Sorry. The pen is at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYwYjj

Comment: I didn't ask where the codepen was, I asked you to post the code here. If codepen is even down or goes away, then your question loses all value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fadeTo()` function for that:

```
$("#element").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
})

$("#element").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
})
```

read more: https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Edit: OP wants flash, OP gets flash:

```
$("#element").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(50, 0.5, function() {
         $(this).fadeTo(50, 1);
    });
 })
```

**Edit2:** 
OP doesn't want parents to flash (eew), but their children instead.. Wait what?

```
$("#element").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find("div").fadeTo(50, 0.5, function() {
         $(this).find("div").fadeTo(50, 1);
    });
 })
```

Some notes about this:
You can replace `find()` by `children()` if the elements you want are DIRECT children of the parent. `find()` goes all the way and also check grandchildren etc.

You can also replace `div` by any selector you want. For example, if you want all the children with class "flashy", you could do: `find(".flashy")`

**Edit 3:**
OP wants flashy thing to be.. Flashing all the time. Final edit (I think):

```
    //Our Holy Grail (or whatever you want to name it.
    var disco = "";

    //Activate discotime!
    $("#element").on("mouseenter", function ()
    {
        disco = setInterval(function ()
        {
            $(element).find("p").fadeToggle(100);
        }, 200);

    });

    //Stop discotime :'(
    $("#element").on("mouseleave", function ()
    {
        $(this).find("p").fadeIn(100);
        clearInterval(disco);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, Jordumus. However, I need the element to only appear briefly before fading out on its own. So, it would essentially flash when the parent container is hovered over. And I need this to happen each time the parent container is hovered over. I hope this makes sense . . .

Comment: Wow, you're quick, Jordumus. Almost there :) Admittedly, I don't know much about JS, but the above code affects the parent element. What I need is to flash a div contained within the parent when the parent is moused over. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, so I probably should have done this to begin with, but I created a pen to better illustrate what I need [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYwYjj]. So, basically, the test text will not be visible until the element container is entered - at that point it will flash. I really appreciate the help, Jordumus. I'm not a smart man . . .

Comment: @MJ12 Leaving work now, I'll have a check this evening while at home.

Comment: @MJ12 I completely forgot about this.. But my answer is edited yet again.

Comment: Ahh, Jordumus, so remember when I admitted that I was not a smart man? Well, I can't get this to work for me. Not sure what I'm missing, but you'd be a daisy if you could fiddle or pen your solution. Again, thanks so much for your time in helping me with this.

Comment: Awesome, Jordumus! I was able to use your example and added a display:none and fadeOut to the paragraph to achieve what I need.  How can I get the paragraph to fade in and out once (a single flash instead of strobe)? That's the final piece of the puzzle :) https://jsfiddle.net/qn6p0td6/1/

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks, Jordumus!

Comment: @MJ12 Pfew, it took us some time, but we managed! Good luck with future code.